# SQL Server text, ntext, image data type problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatatypes

Microsoft announced that: "`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server." And advises to use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.

My question: I have a data type bigger than 8 kb. How can I insert this data to sql? Which data type will solve my problem?

[MSDN document about data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of [nvarchar(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), [varchar(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), and [varbinary(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx).

nvarchar(max) and varchar(max) are for textual information (with nvarchar having unicode support).

varbinary(max) is for binary data (images, files etc).

In all cases, it is documented that using `MAX` `indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.`

Comment: nvarchar(max), varchar(max) allow 4000 (4 Kb) character. varbinary(max). allow 8 kb. i need more than 8kb or 8000 character datatype.

Comment: @maycil - you need to read the documentation again. From the [`varchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) documents: `max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.` and `Use varchar(max) when the sizes of the column data entries vary considerably, and the size might exceed 8,000 bytes.`

Comment: @maycil: you're wrong - varchar(max) allows **2 GByte** of text information, varbinary(max) allows **2 GByte** of binary information

Comment: @marc_s: you are right. i just try it. it worked. thanks for your useful informations.

Answer (score 2):

If it is text data then either `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` (supports unicode). varchar(max) has a maximum storage size of 2^31-1 bytes ([Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).)

If it is binary data then use `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: I guess what OP meant is, since varchar(max) cannot store you more than 8kb of data in a sql row, if OP has data which is more than 8kb, would varchar(max) help? How would it store if its more than 8kb?

Answer (score 0):

You would use either `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)`

If you insert data greater than the 8KB row limitation the data is moved off-row to another page in a ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit.

The following [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx) explains this process in further detail.

I believe the maximum for varchar(max) is 2GB.

Comment: @marc_s - oops! missed that out. Have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused by the "varchar" bit.

It basically means you can use most functions on `varchar(max)` like you would on varchar(50)`or`varchar(1000)`or`varchar(8000)`.

- The (max) datatypes support 2^32-1 bytes
- The non-max types support upto 8000 bytes

So you can have `varchar(50)` or `varchar(1000)` upto `varchar(8000)` but for storing longer strings you'd use `varchar(max)`.

The "max" or "50"/"1000"/"8000" bit simply determines internal storage + maximum string length.

There a few minor differences, such as indexing, of course.